# Wix CustomAction references could not resolve using VS 2017

Tags: c#, wix, visual-studio-2017, custom-action

I've just installed the WIX extension to VS 2017 and I'm trying to load my VS 2015 solution, and it looks like the CustomAction project complains about the references.

Anyone knows something about this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing WiX Toolset v3.11.0.1507 solved the problem

[Wix Toolset v3.11.0.1507](http://wixtoolset.org/releases/v3-11-0-1507/)